# Wacom Inkling produces wave-like distortions

Tags: printer

I just bought a [Wacom Inkling device](http://inkling.wacom.com/) and found it produce wave distortions on sketches, like this

[image]

Can it be fixed/calibrated or should be returned to the seller?